# Ruby on Rails: create records for multiple models with one form and one submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

I have a 3 models: quote, customer, and item. Each quote has one customer and one item. I would like to create a new quote, a new customer, and a new item in their respective tables when I press the submit button. I have looked at other questions and railscasts and either they don't work for my situation or I don't know how to implement them.

quote.rb

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quote_number
  has_one :customer
  has_one :item
end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
  #unsure of what to put here
  #a customer can have multiple quotes, so would i use has_many or belongs_to?
  belongs_to :quote
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  #also unsure about this
  #each item can also be in multiple quotes
  belongs_to :quote
```

quotes_controller.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @quote = Quote.new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @item = item.new
  end

  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(params[:quote])
    @quote.save
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    @customer.save
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.save
  end
end
```

items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.save
  end
end
```

customers_controller.rb

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    @customer.save
  end
end
```

my form for quotes/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @customer do |builder| %>
    <%= label_tag :firstname %>
    <%= builder.text_field :firstname %>
    <%= label_tag :lastname %>
    <%= builder.text_field :lastname %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for @item do |builder| %>
    <%= label_tag :name %>
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
    <%= label_tag :description %>
    <%= builder.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>
  <%= label_tag :quote_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :quote_number %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I try submitting that I get an error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item, customer
```

So to try and fix it I updated the attr_accessible in quote.rb to include :item, :customer but then I get this error:

```
Item(#) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try making :name and :description accessible and :firstname and :lastname accessible in their respective models.

Comment: @lilwupster I did that but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To submit a form and it's associated children you need to use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

To do this, you need to declare it at the model for the controller you are going to use (in your case, it looks like the Quote Controller.

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quote_number
  has_one :customer
  has_one :item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers, :items
end
```

Also, you need to make sure you declare which [attributes are accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) so you avoid other mass assignment errors.

Comment: welp, I put accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers, :items and also tried :customer, :item but neither seemed to work.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the attributes are accessible (link above)?

Comment: yep i tried that; it didn't work, so i went with attr_protected :id on all of them to make sure i didn't miss any, but now it spits out the error "ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in QuotesController#create   <br />    Item(#) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#)"

Comment: Did you fix the error in your controller that has this:
`@item = item.new`
that should be 
`@item = Item.new`

I think that's the cause, because item is the wrong type.

Comment: it was already capitalized; that was a typo on my part. thanks for the help but i think i'm going about it wrong. i'm going to have a customer has_many :quotes and a quote belongs_to a customer

Answer (score 1):

If you want add info for diferent models i suggest to apply nested_model_form like this reference: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast.

This solution is very simple and cleanest.

Comment: Do I need to change my model files at all? That screencast uses a has_many, belongs_to relationship, while I am using a has_one, and has_many, but I have no idea if that's right. I have tried changing my the '@' in my variables in index.html.erb to ':' but it didn't work.