# Submit form with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I need a way to save 2 or more models in one form. Mymodel has two inputs (s_url and i_url). Here is a test form that I set up.

```
<%= form_for :mymodel, :url => mymodels_path do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :s_url %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :i_url %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :s_url %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :i_url %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And here is the Controller:

```
def new
    @mymodel = Mymodel.new
end

 def create
    @mymodel = Mymodel.new(s_url: params[:s_url], i_url: params[:i_url])
    if @mymodel.save
      redirect_to some_index_path(@some_index, :anchor => params[:s_url])
    end
  end
```

When I save, it only submits one of the models instead of both. Also, I don't know how many models the user will save. I just hardcoded 2 into the form in order to test if they would both send. But in the end, the form will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not so elegant solution is to do the following

```
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag 's_url[0]' %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag 'i_url[0]' %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag 's_url[1]' %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag 'i_url[1]' %>
    </p>
```

Back in your controller, `params[:s_url]` and `params[:i_url]` will contain arrays of all the values.

Using jQuery you could easily generate the form with as many records as you want, and even add more on the fly.

However, this is not a clean solution.

A bit slower but way cleaner, is to pass a collection of your model to the form. This will create some extra server side calls when you want to increase the list, but I still find it to be a much better solution.

Example from [fields_for documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
    Project #<%= project_fields.index %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Of course, best would be to use a client-side MVC framework like Angular or Ember, but I'm not sure how feasible is this for you.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to loop through the `params[:s_url]`/`[:i_url]` arrays in the controller to create multiple model instances?

Answer (score 0):

```
def new
    @mymodel = Mymodel.new
end

 def create
    @mymodel = Mymodel.new(s_url: params[:s_url], i_url: params[:i_url])
    if @mymodel.save
      redirect_to some_index_path(@some_index, :anchor => params[:s_url])
    end
  end
```

In your controller code's both actions, I see you have only model (`Mymodel`) and you are creating an instance of that model and saving it (`@mymodel.save`). So, how can you expect it to submit to two models?

If you really want to create and save two models in the same action, then you would do something like this (depending on how your models look like):

```
def create
  # creating two models
  @mymodel_1 = Mymodel1.new(s_url: params[:s_url])
  @mymodel_2 = Mymodel2.new(i_url: params[:i_url])

  # saving two models
  if @mymodel_1.save && @mymodel_2.save
    redirect_to some_index_path(@some_index, :anchor => params[:s_url])
  end
end
```

But, you can't redirect_to multiple model instances at a time. You have to redirect to somewhere else.

Comment: But, what if I don't know how many models the user wants to create? In the final app there won't only be 2 models. The user will be able to add more inputs into the form dynamically. I was thinking with something like `params['s_url'].each` or something

Comment: You have to loop through all the user inputs and then dynamically generate  the model names and their params based on user inputs and  and then create all of those models, that's possible. But. you have to save all the models with separate `save` calls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330843/ruby-on-rails-create-records-for-multiple-models-with-one-form-and-one-submit
and
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/creating-a-rails-website-implementing-multiple-models-on-one-page
These might be useful.